# Time complexity for the multiplication of three rectangular matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms

For the multiplication of two matrix, one can use the classical methods, such as [strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm), to reduce the time complexity. Here, I just wonder if there is any efficent algorithm aiming at the multiplication of three matrix? Namely, For
$$
D= A*B*C
$$
Or specially,
$$
D= O^T*B*O
$$
where $T$ represents for transposition. Thank you.

Comment: I've been searching the literature and have not been able to identify a source that address your question adequately. The closest I could found is: http://marco.bodrato.it/papers/Bodrato2008-StrassenLikeMatrixMultiplicationForSquares.pdf.